# Can't get content from URL with PHP

Tags: php, url, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the xml content from an URL with PHP, but all the methods that I tried returned empty string or error. The URL is: http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=NATU3|PETR4|ITSA4|

First, I attempted with simplexml_load_file, and received error message. Then I attempted with file_get_contents, but is returning empty.

At last, I uses cURL, using the following commands:

```
        $ch=curl_init();
        $timeout=5;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

        // Get URL content
        $lines_string=curl_exec($ch);
        // close handle to release resources
        curl_close($ch);
```

But nothing is being returned too. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I tried it and got the XML with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you don't use `$lines_string` correctly in the remainder of the program because this simply works:

```
$ch=curl_init();
$timeout=5;
$url = 'http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=NATU3|PETR4|ITSA4|';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$lines_string=curl_exec($ch);
print_r($lines_string);
curl_close($ch);
```

and returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ComportamentoPapeis><Papel Codigo="NATU3" Nome="NATURA ON      NM" Ibovespa="#" Data="19/12/2014 16:47:14" Abertura="31,00" Minimo="30,74" Maximo="31,44" Medio="31,06" Ultimo="30,88" Oscilacao="-0,12"/><Papel Codigo="PETR4" Nome="PETROBRAS PN" Ibovespa="#" Data="19/12/2014 16:47:49" Abertura="9,94" Minimo="9,57" Maximo="9,98" Medio="9,72" Ultimo="9,75" Oscilacao="3,06"/><Papel Codigo="ITSA4" Nome="ITAUSA PN      N1" Ibovespa="#" Data="19/12/2014 16:47:47" Abertura="9,53" Minimo="9,42" Maximo="9,63" Medio="9,55" Ultimo="9,52" Oscilacao="1,27"/></ComportamentoPapeis>
```